# play video over my content AS2

Tags: flash, video, actionscript-2

I have a flash app that is going to be run in full screen from an swf. I need to play a video over the content when user does click in a button. I hear audio from the net stream, but I do not see the video. I've tried with flv and mp4 files, all in the same folder than the swf.

Here's my code:

```
var my_video:Video; 
my_video = new Video();
my_video._height=600;
my_video._width=800;
my_video._x = 0;
my_video._y = 0;
addChild(my_video);

var my_nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
my_nc.connect(null);
var my_ns:NetStream = new NetStream(my_nc);
my_video.attachVideo(my_ns);
my_ns.play("video.mp4");
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a component in your library, it depends on your version of the IDE. Either Video, MediaDisplay or the more recent FLVPlayback all work in AS2. Then you will see video.

Ok if you create a new AS2 file in CS5.5 then open the components panel you can double click the FLVPlayback component and it will put it on the stage and in your library, just delete the one off the stage as you can attach it with code, you just need it in the library to use it.

[image]

The following code will demonstrate this working:

```
import mx.video.FLVPlayback;

var video:FLVPlayback = this.attachMovie("FLVPlayback", "my_video", 10);
video.contentPath = "http://www.helpexamples.com/flash/video/water.flv";
video.setSize(640, 480);
```

Have a look at the documentation to help you understand what properties are available to help you understand how this component works:

[FLVPlayback Adobe docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00002331.html)

Comment: If i'm using Flash cs5.5, how can I add one of those components?

Comment: I googled about it, but I don't really know if I have it or how to get it. It says it has premade skins, but I don't want any skins on the video or premade control buttons, because It is a very specific use I need to satisfy and I need to be able to put it over the whole document, as if it was some kind of full screen. I don't really know what it is exactly or how can I use it, so I can't answer that question; sorry. If you can explain it to me a little, I will mark your answer as right and good, for sure. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Yes you can use it without controls, I'll help you Monday when I get back home.

Comment: Then I guess it's just what I need, thank you for helping me on Monday.

Comment: I have added a code example for you. I urge you to use AS3 if possible as AS2 is pretty ancient now, but that is your decision and may be a requirement in your case, good luck.

Comment: It's a requirement, saddly. That's pretty cool. I saw the documentation, it doesn't seem like I'll need to create a netstream, am I right? Thank you.

Comment: The netsream is created for you under the hood with the FLVPlayback component, its a big leap forward compared to the old components, usually you only need to create a netsream if you are using Flash Media Server to stream the video.